# Two projects in one solution using two different versions of same dll

Tags: c#, dll, siemens

I'm trying to implement the solution of the following earlier question and I don't want to hijack that question, so I'm posting a new one. I hope this is ok.
[Same DLLs two different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994614/same-dlls-two-different-versions)

I have a project structure like the following

- Client

  - Form1.cs
- TiaOpennessV15_1

  - TiaOpenness.cs
  - V151

    - Siemens.Engineering.dll (15.1.0.0)
- TiaOpennessV16

  - TiaOpenness.cs
  - V16

    - Siemens.Engineering.dll (16.0.0.0)

Both of the TiaOpenness-projects are using a dll-file called Siemens.Engineering, though they use the versions 15.1.0.0 and 16.0.0.0 respectively. I have put these dll-files in the seperate projects under the folders V151 and V16 respectively. I have referenced the different dll-files in each of the TiaOpenness-projects and set "Copy Local" to **False**.

In my client project (Windows Forms) I have the following App.config code.

#### App.config [Solved]

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Siemens.Engineering" publicKeyToken="d29ec89bac048f84" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.0.0" newVersion="15.1.0.0"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.1.0.1-16.0.0.0" newVersion="16.0.0.0"/>
      <codeBase version="15.1.0.0" href="V151\Siemens.Engineering.dll"/>
      <codeBase version="16.0.0.0" href="V16\Siemens.Engineering.dll"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

When I fire up the client, I can verify that the client is using the 16.0.0.0 version of the dll in both cases by running the code below.

```cs
private void FindInstancesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<int> instances = new List<int>();

  using (Base core = new Base(new TiaOpennessV15_1.TiaOpenness()))
  {
    instances.AddRange(core.ListInstanceIds());
  }

  using (Base core = new Base(new TiaOpennessV16.TiaOpenness()))
  {
    instances.AddRange(core.ListInstanceIds());
  }
}
```

If I remove the App.config code from above, I get the following error.

> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Siemens.Engineering, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d29ec89bac048f84' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Note that the same dialog is having an **Inner Exception** that states the version 15.1.0.0 instead of version 16.0.0.0, but with the same PublicKeyToken.

I have checked that both dll-files are moved to the folders V151 and V16 respectively in the bin/debug-folder. I don't know what else to do anymore... Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1 @KlausGütter:
I want to be able to use my client to access both TiaOpenness-projects (class libraries) where each project should use its own version of the dlls. The different versions return different instance ids and I should have a set of two different integers in the instances-list in the FindInstancesButton_Click-function above.

What is happening right now is that both TiaOpenness-projects are using the same dll even though I am trying to use the different dlls.

EDIT 2 @KlausGütter:
Thank you Klaus! It turned out that there were automatically a bindingRedirect inserted in to the config file after compilation. I didn't see the post you were linking before, but sure enough I had to insert my own bindingRedirects in to the config file and set the  to false. After a rebuild of the solution, it worked great! Thank

I have edited the config code above to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: Could you please make clearer what the desired behaviour is? Do you want to have *both* DLLs loaded into the process?

Comment: @KlausGütter Hello Klaus. I have tried to explain more clearly in an edit what the desired behaviour is. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715564/using-2-different-versions-of-the-same-dll)?

Comment: @KlausGütter Thank you very much Klaus, the link you posted had the correct answer! I'll post that as an answer here shortly. Oh man, I have spent 2 weeks on this before I turned to StackOverflow... Thanks a bunch, again!